# I want to print the following pattern

Tags: c++

```
    1
    3 2
    6 5 4
    10 9 8 7
```

I want to print the following pattern. I have tried very hard but couldn't make the code for it. I have tried everything which came up to my mind.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i, j, n;
  cin >> n;
  int k = 0;
  for (i = 1;i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      k++;
      printf("%d ", k);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

the other code which i tried is this.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i, j, n;
  cin >> n;
  int k = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
      k++;
      printf("%d ",j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried, preferably a [mcve], and indicate where you are running into problems.

Comment: i am not able to print the no in reverse order.```#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int i,j,n;
 cin>>n;
 int k=0;
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
   k++;
   printf("%d ",k);              
} 
            printf("\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add to the post what you wrote in the comment.

Comment: no i did it by my self. the other code which i tried is this.```#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int i,j,n;
 cin>>n;
 int k=0;
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
  for(j=i;j>=1;j--){
   k++;
   printf("%d ",j);              
} 
            printf("\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: There is an [edit] link under the tags of question to [edit] the question if you want to fix it. Have you tried to debug it step by step to get an idea what's happening where? Do you have a clear idea with which value each row should start and end? Sometimes programming starts on paper... ;-)

Comment: `std::cout << "1\n3 2\n6 5 4\n10 9 8 7";` All done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int previousRow = 0;
for(int row = 1; row <= 4; row++)
{
    int rowTracker = row;

    for(int col = 0; col < row; col++)
    {
        cout<<rowTracker - col + previousRow<<" ";
    }
    previousRow += row;
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<iostream>

void printPattern(unsigned numlevels)
{
  unsigned last_num = 1;
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < numlevels; ++i)
  {
    unsigned next_num = i + last_num;
    for(unsigned j = next_num; j >= last_num; --j)
    {
      std::cout << j << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    last_num = next_num + 1;
  }
}
int main()
{
  unsigned n;
  std::cin >> n;
  printPattern(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a stack to implement this. Here is a working answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i, j, n;
  stack<int> st;
  cin >> n;
  int k = 0;
  for(i = 1;i <= n; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      k++;
      st.push(k);
    }
    while(!st.empty()){
      printf("%d ", st.top());
      st.pop();
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before reading the code blow, you should really try to do it yourself. This problem is obviously for practice and to develop the programming muscle. Just getting the answer is not going to help. 
The issue with your code is that for each row, the range you want to print is not being determined correctly. You should first find the range and then print the numbers. Ther can be multiple approaches to it. Below is one of them.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ 
    int max = i*(i+1)/2;
    int min = i*(i-1)/2 + 1;
    for(j=max;j>=min;j--){ 
        printf("%d ",j); 
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 4; // suppose print 4 lines
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int i0 = (i + 1) * i / 2;  // first number of line i
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            cout << i0 - j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanx everyone for your responses. I was able to do it on my own. Below is what I did. if there is any correction let me know

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i,j,n,temp;
    cin>>n;
    int k=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        k=k+i,temp=k;
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
           cout<<temp<<+"  ";
           temp--;

    }

            cout<<("\n");
    }
}
```